# control markers matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, marker

how do I control the markertype and the markersize in such a plor?

```
x = 0:pi/10:2*pi;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = sin(x-0.25);
y3 = sin(x-0.5);

figure
plot(x,y1,'g',x,y2,'b--o',x,y3,'c*')
```

Can I use the arguments

```
('Color',[...],'Linestyle','...','LineWidth',[],'Marker','...','MarkerSize',[])
```

Thanks

I figured it out

```
h =    plot(x,y1,'g',x,y2,'b--o',x,y3,'c*')
set(h(1),'Color',[...],'Marker','...','MarkerSize',[],h(2),'Color', [...],'Marker','...','MarkerSize',[]);
```

Comment: Please post the answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
h =    plot(x,y1,'g',x,y2,'b--o',x,y3,'c*')
set(h(1),'Color',[...],'Marker','...','MarkerSize',[],h(2),'Color', [...],'Marker','...','MarkerSize',[]);
```